# Stored procedure with char[n] input parameter not getting called from EF with string SqlParameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, sqlparameter

My SQL Server stored procedure expects two `char(2)` parameters.

I am passing it string as following but the stored procedure returns no data.

```
this.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("A", this._A));//this._A is string type
this.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("B", this._B));
```

I have tried adding `SqlType.Char` and `Size` parameter as well but no success. Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: This doesn't look like an EF6 question?

Comment: Well, we'll need to see the **(1)** stored procedure code, and **(2)** the table structures involved, and **(3)** some sample data you're using to test this

Answer (score 0):

```
this.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@A", this._A));
this.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@B", this._B));

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //error occurs here
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {

    }
}



var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@A", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
sqlParameter.Value = this.A;
```

did you try this

Comment: It says Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: then obviously, your stored procedure isn't returning any results ....